# WIFI Problems on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 AMD Ryzen 4000u

Tags: wireless, ideapad

My wifi connection on ubuntu is very unstable. Every few minutes I lose the wifi connection or I just get very very low Downloadspeeds (just a few Bytes/s). I dont know what to do. It works just fine on windows (i use dualboot).
I tried so far:
-turning off powermanagement
-use different Kernel
-looking for driverupdates (found nothing)
Can someone please help me?

My wifi driver: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

(I am new on Ubuntu or Linux/GNU in general)

Answer (score 0):

RTL8821ce doesn't have a very good driver support from realtek which results in such unstable WiFi behavior. As far as I know the current driver used in Ubuntu is a DKMS module packed using the source of [this repository](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) (I'm not sure about that). But there are some fixes on the README for unstable connections that might help.
to quote it:

> #### Unstable connection - slowdowns or dropouts
>
> The problem may be due to the periodic scanning of access points by the network applet.
>
> > This fix worked helpful on Pop! _OS/Ubuntu 20.10 and Fedora 33. Both with GNOME and NetworkManager. [#179](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/179)
>
> Set the BSSID from your network applet. In GNOME this can be done in `WiFi Settings > Your profile > Identity > BSSID`.
>
> We are going to disable the *Connectivity Check* option in NetworkManager. This by editing the file in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf` and adding the following instructions at the end:
>
> ```
> [connectivity]
> .set.enabled=false
> ```
>
> Then, just reboot or restart the NetworkManager unit to fix the problem.